# People created by non-administrator role are not allowed to edit their content

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I created a role called `site manager`. This role is allowed to create new users. The problem is that users created by this user are not allowed to edit their contents. The *Access denied* is reported. But people created by the *Administrator* or people who signup for the site, can edit their content.

This is the permissions of *site manager* (for *Users* and content type *Image*):

[image]

and this one

[image]

Do any of you know why this happens?

---

**UPDATE**

After installing devel node access module I see this for a node which its author is **z jafari**

[image]

**This user is allowed to delete its content but unable to edit it.**

I also tried [content access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module, gave appropriate permission but it didn't work again.

Comment: Do you problem exist yet?

Comment: @zhilevan yes unfortunately

Comment: It seems some strange, I have suggestion only for debug purpose,please create another role, and set permission for it  and try create a user by `site manager` and set that role to it.and tell me the result of it

Comment: There are about 130 users who are created by `site manager`, and about 8000 contents are created by these people. No more user will be created, the problem is current users.

Comment: @zhilevan I created a new role with the permission of `Authenticated Users`. assigned that role to some of those users, it didn't work again

Comment: Ok, tnx for try it, I go lunch and think about it,come back soon and try to solve it with each other ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31747/discussion-between-zhilevan-and-drupalist).

Comment: it strange and need some discussion and try & error debug .i invite you to discussion chat

Comment: @zhilevan ok I will answer there

Comment: Ok, I left discuss chat,I think solving this problem need some debugging.

Comment: Have you tried to check all the checkboxes to see if you missed one of them?

Comment: @Namari  the problem solved and I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I installed Edit Limit module to limit the time which a user can edit its comment. But I made a mistake by checking the checkbox of node edit.

**many thanks to all the guys who helped me.**

Answer (score 1):

Because they don't have any roles associated with them. You need to add a role to the new users giving them the permissions you want them to have.

Comment: But permissions of authenticated users are assigned to them, right? Authenticated users are able to edit their content. If their role wasnot *Authenticated* they wouldnot be able to create new content.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well in that case, it sounds like there are permissions problems elsewhere causing it. Have you tried clearing caches?

Comment: Yes, I guess as Tom said I should check for the author and compare the both kind of users

Answer (score 1):

The "Configure Block" button is confusing me a bit. But anyways, check to make sure the users are listed as the author of the nodes and use the devel module to compare an administrator created user and a site manager created user.

Also, give the edit any node permission to authenticated and check what happens.

Comment: I used devel module, but actually there was no significant difference between them (except uid, time of its creation and some other stuff) . they all were assigned authenticated role

Comment: Very odd. Anything about it in the log? As a last resort, I'd use a rule to apply the authenticated role but doubt that'd help. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is coming from the "site manager" permissions and he is not able to created a user with the correct ones.

Have you tried to add: "Access the content overview page" and "Administer content" to site manager?

Use this code and log in as one of the users:

```
  global $user;
  dsm(user_role_permissions($user->roles));
```

Comment: for no reason I gave 100 points to you ;)